# MySQL Joining Two Table ID's to Produce Results from One Table to Another

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've tried a whole slew of examples / answered questions on stackoverflow but I can't seem to accomplish what I need.

I have a PHP / MySQL tool I'm working on to track projects for myself. I thought it'd be a good idea to optimize the largest table right off the hop, so I chose to store ID's in the Project table as opposed to full names. I'm looking to link that ID from the Project table to the actual Name in another table when viewing results via PHP, but of course I want the actual database column to just contain the ID. I believe this is possible, I just can't figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Table - Projects

```
ID | CustomerID | Summary  | Phase
---------------------------------
1  | 61         | Project1 | 3
2  | 42         | Project2 | 3
3  | 33         | Project3 | 5
```

Table - Customers

```
ID   | CustomerName
--------------------
61   | Customer 1
42   | Customer 2
33   | Customer 3
```

Right now when I call the "CustomerID" row from the Projects Table, it displays the CustomerID number as expected. I would like it to pull the CustomerName from the Customers table instead, matching the Customers.ID column to the Projects.CustomerID column.

Is this possible? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: just select it? in the select? can you post the query you are using?

Comment: Right now, I'm just using

    `SELECT CustomerID FROM Projects WHERE ID = "1";`

for example. 

I've tried a few other examples I found but I'm getting nowhere with them:

`mysql> SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers INNER JOIN Customers ON (Projects.CustomerID = Customers.ID);`
`ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'Customers'`
`mysql> SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers WHERE ID = Projects.CustomerID;`
`ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Projects.CustomerID' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Projects
JOIN Customers ON Customers.ID = Projects.CustomerID
WHERE Projects.ID = "1"
```

Comment: I think you've got it! Let me just play around with this a bit!

Comment: The first 2 lines work wonderfully: `mysql> SELECT CustomerName FROM Projects JOIN Customers ON Customers.ID = Projects.CustomerID;` but as soon as I add the WHERE clause, I get `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: OK I goofed somewhere and it looks to be working now from the CLI, going to try it in my PHP.

Comment: Working great everywhere but 1 spot! But it's not the SQL's fault there! Thank you so much for your help, I've been able to apply it to a few more columns now that I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work:

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers JOIN Projects ON CustomerID = ID;
```

You are selecting the customername from customers and joining that table with projects where customerid is equal to id.

Comment: `ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'ID' in on clause is ambiguous`

Comment: I get it now - changed the last ID to Customers.ID

Comment: @cwaddilove all you have to do is change ID to whatever ID you are passing thats all