# PHP / MySQL Joining - Nested While?

Tags: php, mysql, join, while-loop

Following my [previous question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516623/mysql-joining-two-table-ids-to-produce-results-from-one-table-to-another)

I'm trying to get my CustomerName <-> ID Conversion working entirely, and it's working fine on my display / edit pages in a while loop, but I'm confused how to get it going on my project list pages.

For example, the following code will display all the projects in my Projects table, with the CustomerID instead of CustomerName. I have the SQL to convert from CustomerID to CustomerName, but how on earth would I inject that into this code?

**Project List**

```
<?php
include_once('includes/config.inc.php');
if ($connection->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $connection->connect_errno . ") " . $connection->connect_error;
}

$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Projects");;

$CustomerNameResult = $connection->query("SELECT CustomerName FROM Customers JOIN Projects ON Projects.CustomerID = Customers.ID");;

echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Project ID</th>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Summary</th>
<th>Phase</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><p class='content'><a href='display_project.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['ID'] . "</p></td>";
  echo "<td><p class='content'>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</p></td>";
  echo "<td><p class='content'>" . $row['Summary'] . "</p></td>";
  echo "<td><p class='content'>" . $row['Phase'] . "</p></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

I've tried nesting another while loop in there but it just makes a mess of things in the first column and doesn't actually put them where they belong.

Thanks in advanced for any comments or answers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Projects JOIN Customers ON Projects.CustomerID = Customers.ID");
```

You will have all the data of the customer and the project that you can use after fetching... And you can delete the `$CustomerNameResult`